# ASP.net EF6 Gridview Update Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

I am using Visual Studio 2015, Entity Framework 6 and C#.  I have a gridview that will delete, but I need it to edit a row when edit is clicked.  I made a stored procedure, but I cant get that to work in it either.

I have two stored procedures (one for testing):

```
 spUpdatePizza3(Size, PizzaID)
 spUpdatePizza2(Size, Crust, Sauce, OrderCost,PizzaID)
```

This is what I have:

```
 protected void gvExOr_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        using (PizzaParlor2Entities po = new PizzaParlor2Entities())
        {

            String PizzaID = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
            String Size = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[6].Text.ToString();

            //  String Crust = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[7].Text.ToString();
            //  String Sauce = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[8].Text.ToString();
            // String Delivery = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[9].Text.ToString();
            //   String OrderCost = gvExOr.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[10].Text.ToString();

          //  string size = gvExOr.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text;
         //   lblTest.Text = size;

            gvExOr.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            //  po.spUpdatePizza3(Size, Convert.ToInt32(PizzaID));
            //  po.spUpdatePizza2(Size, Crust, Sauce, Convert.ToDecimal(OrderCost), Convert.ToInt32(PizzaID));

        }

        gvExOr.DataBind();

    }
```

Question:  How do I get the row to update using a stored procedure (or any method, at this point) with Entity Framework 6?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OnRowUpdating event to actually save the data:

```
protected void OnRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = gvExOr.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var pizzaId = gvExOr.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0];  // Set this in markup of grid
    string size = (row.FindControl("txtSize") as TextBox).Text;  // Assumes you have EditItemTemplate
    using (PizzaParlor2Entities entities = new PizzaParlor2Entities ())
    {
        Pizza pizza = entities.Pizzas.First(p => p.PizzaID == pizzaID);
        pizza.Size = size;
        entities.SaveChanges();
    }
    gvExOr.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

See http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-GridView-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet.aspx